# Angular 11 assets not found after build

Tags: html, angular, http-status-code-404, assets

I have a problem with assets folder in my angular app - after building an app, the assets couldn't be found.

My index.html file:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>CodigitalExternal</title>
  <base href="./">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">  
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

My angular.json file:

```json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "MyApp": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "deployUrl": "dist/",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "aot": true,
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "MyApp:build",
            "deployUrl": "/"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "MyApp:build:production"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "MyApp"
}
```

Because of **"deployUrl": "dist/"** in build options, I have to change it to "/" in serve options.

And then, I can load my images like:

```html
<img src="/assets/icons/closeX-circle.blue.24x24.svg" />
```

Everything works perfectly on localhost , but after building and deploying to the server, assets cannot be found. One solution for working assets I found is to change the paths by adding the **dist** prefix in src like that:

```html
<img src="dist/assets/icons/closeX-circle.blue.24x24.svg" />
```

But then, the assets don't work on localhost. I know there is something incorrect with my configuration, but I don't know what.

Comment: If you use `src="/foo/bar"`, then it will ignore the basePath. You have to use relative urls instead (so remove the leading slash). I personnally added the same basePath on my localhost build (so I go to `localhost:4200/foo/`) to make everything similar.

Comment: I finally found a solution for my problem. I had to change all paths to images from `src="/assets/icons/..."` to `src="dist/assets/icons/..."`. Also I added `{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' },` in providers array in my app.module.ts and removed `"deployUrl": "/"` from serve options.
But then I had a problem with refreshing my app on localhost - I was getting **Cannot get** after refreshing any page, so I added `"baseHref": "dist"` in serve options. Everything is working fine at this moment. 
@Random - thank you for your comment - it helped me understand how paths are generated